# Inserting 1 Million Records into MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, insert, iterator

I want to insert 1 million records into a database with same values but unique primary keys. I don't want to write the records first into a file and then import that file into the database.
Please provide some efficient query that I can run for this.

Comment: Are you using any programming language ?

Comment: command-line-based batch job can help. You can write such batch job in PHP CLI, C#, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT 
        INSERT INTO your_table SELECT NULL, field1, field2;
        SET @x = @x + 1; 
    UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END
```

and execute this procedure with p1 as number of records you want.
Just to be clear: in `SELECT NULL, field1...` NULL param is for *id field* which will be autogenerated if defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a row-generator: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code

e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO table_name
       (id, c1,c2,c3,c4)
SELECT gen.n, 1,2,3,4
  FROM generator_1m;
```

Comment: A row generator is great, but a bit advanced I think.

Comment: @Gustav Bertram Well, just copy & paste. I've changed the link so it goes to the ready-to-use code at the end of the article.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. <strike>Use `INSERT DELAYED`. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):</strike>

   > If you use the `DELAYED` keyword, the server puts the row or rows to be inserted into a buffer, and the client issuing the `INSERT DELAYED` statement can then continue immediately. If the table is in use, the server holds the rows.

   As @Matt points out in a comment, `INSERT DELAYED` has been deprecated as of MySQL 5.6.6. In 5.7, it's accepted but ignored, and the manual says that it will be removed in a future release of MySQL. Don't use it.
2. Use transactions. MySQL will know that it doesn't need to update the indices until you commit the changes.

Comment: INSERT DELAYED is deprecated since 5.6

Answer (score 0):

set your table primary key as auto_increment in mysql.

am showing you php example with while condition. follow this simple logic in any language to achieve.

```
$a = 150000; // set the count you need
$i=0;
while($i < $a)
{


$name = 'sample';

$segment = "insert into table values
(null,'$name')";



$ss = mysql_query($segment);



echo mysql_error();

$i++;


}
```

Comment: The original poster specifically asked for a MySQL query.